# Enumerator over a sublist (linked list)

Tags: c#, .net-core, linked-list

I am trying to make an enumerator that iterates over a sublist within a linked list. To do this, I'm explicitly keeping track of the two nodes `Head` and `Tail` that bound the sublist. My goal is to be able to call a `foreach` loop over the linked list, to iterate over all the elements of the sublist.

#### What `foreach` wants to do:

The `foreach` loop first initializes an enumerator, in my case with the required list `list` and a variable linked list node `node` from which it will ask the `Value` during the loop.

Once the loop has been initialized, it repeats the following pattern:

1. Call the `MoveNext()` method, which 'increments' the list
2. Retrieve `Current` and return it to wherever it's called

Repeat until `MoveNext() == false`.

#### How I've currently written my enumerator

Since the first step is to move, rather than to return a value, I figured I could initialize my enumerator like this:

```cs
this.list = list;
this.node = list.Head.Previous // Initialize node to be the element before Head
```

Where `Head` is the first element of the sublist to be shown.

Then, I tried to implement the logic for `MoveNext()` and `Current` like this:

```cs
public T Current => node.Value;
object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
public bool MoveNext()
{
    node = node.Next;
    return node != list.Tail.Next;
}
```

Where `Tail` is the last element of the sublist to be shown.

But in some cases, because this implementation of a linked list is circular, `list.Tail.Next` can be `list.Head`, meaning that `MoveNext()` will return `false` without even getting the chance to return a single value.

Is there a way to refactor the enumerator to make sure it iterates over the entire sublist instead of just short-circuiting, both when `list.Tail.Next` does and doesn't point to `list.Head`?

Comment: Does this mean that your linked list will never be empty?

Comment: I intend to handle the edge cases after I got the more broad usage working. But you're right, if the linked list is empty or if the sublist is empty then `MoveNext()` should return `false` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, there seems to be no cases where the first call to `MoveNext` would return false.

You could just add an extra piece of state called `Moved`:

```
private bool Moved { get; set; } = false;

public bool MoveNext()
{
    node = node.Next;
    var retVal = !Moved || node != list.Tail.Next;
    Moved = true;
    return retVal;
}
```

An extra state is definitely needed here, because if you only have one element, we have no way to tell whether we have iterated over it or not, as `node = node.Next` does not change the state of the enumerator.

Comment: Thanks to Gert-Jan's answer, I found a bug in my code, I'll fix that first and then try your implementation as I cannot guarantee that it will work with my currently bugged implementation of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    bool returnValue = node != list.Tail; 
    node = node.Next;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This loops over the entire linked list, starting from `Head`. That's actually a bug in my implementation of the linked list.

Comment: I think I fixed the bug so I tested out your implementation. Unfortunately, it shows all but the last item in both the underpopulated and the overpopulated cases.